# Azure Function not published after docker build and deploy

Tags: c#, azure, docker, asp.net-core, azure-functions

I'm trying to deploy Azure Function in Linux Docker using azure pipelines. Locally I don't have any problem, but after committing those changes to Azure, everything passes successfully, a new tag is created, but function is not found.
I'm using Azure Function v4.
Below is a sample of my azure pipeline yml file:

```
  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build and push stage
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build and push an image to container registry
      inputs:
        command: buildAndPush
        repository: $(imageRepository)
        dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)
        containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
        tags: |
          $(tag)
```

[image]

When I change tag in Deployment Center to one I've created locally function is available:
[image]

Am I missing some step in azure pipelines for function publishing?

Comment: From what I can see, the yaml builds your docker image and pushes it up into a container registry. Depending on the value of `dockerRegistryServiceConnection`, I'd check to see whether the image is in e.g. your Azure Container Registry, or in Docker Hub, etc. You'll then need to add an extra [`AzureFunctionAppContainer@1`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-rm-functionapp-containers?view=azure-devops) step to deploy from the container image to your function.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I don't have that step for now, but I change tag to the latest manually, so I now that tag is properly set.